Cannot modify Pandas dataframe read from Excel file
I have a function to apply to a DataFrame as follows:
import pandas as pd
from math import comb
from itertools import combinations

def find_match_total(row, total_col, sum_cols):
    size = len(row)
    data = row.loc[row.index.isin(sum_cols)].to_dict()
    total= row[total_col]
    keys = data.keys()
    values = data.values()
    break_outer_loop = False
    for i in range(2,size+1):
        if break_outer_loop:
            break
        key_combinations = combinations(keys,i)
        value_combinations = combinations(values,i)
        for cols, values in zip(key_combinations, value_combinations):
            if sum(values)==total:
                break_outer_loop= True
                print(cols, values)
                for key in row.index:
                    if key not in cols and key in sum_cols:
                        print(key, row[key])
                        row[key]= 0.0 if row[key].dtype =='float64' else 0
                break

These are two test data:
data1={'a':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'b':[11,12,13,14,15,16],'x':[11,12,13,14,15,16],'c':[12,12,16,14,15,16],'f':[12,12,13,14,15,16]}



data2={'columns': ['c', 'a', 'b', 'x', 'f'],
     'data': [[786.6238018663737,
       589.9678513997803,
       196.65595046659342,
       0.016,
       0.0],
      [786.6238018663737, 589.9678513997803, 196.65595046659342, 0.016, 0.0],
      [786.6238018663737, 589.9678513997803, 196.65595046659342, 0.016, 0.0],
      [786.6238018663737, 589.9678513997803, 196.65595046659342, 0.016, 0.0],
      [786.6238018663737, 589.9678513997803, 196.65595046659342, 0.016, 0.0],
      [786.6238018663737, 589.9678513997803, 196.65595046659342, 0.016, 0.0],
      [786.6238018663737, 589.9678513997803, 196.65595046659342, 0.016, 0.0],
      [786.6238018663737, 589.9678513997803, 196.65595046659342, 0.016, 0.0]]}

Link for excel file: Excel file Google sheet Link
I create dataframes from data1, data2 and from excel file:
df_test1= pd.DataFrame(data1)
df_test2= pd.DataFrame(data2['data'], columns=data2['columns'])
df_test3= pd.read_excel('D:/Book2.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')

I check the df_test2 and df_test3
print(df_test2==df_test3)

Result is similar structure and values:
      c     a     b     x     f
0  True  True  True  True  True
1  True  True  True  True  True
2  True  True  True  True  True
3  True  True  True  True  True
4  True  True  True  True  True
5  True  True  True  True  True
6  True  True  True  True  True
7  True  True  True  True  True

I apply the function to each DataFrame:
df_test1.apply(find_match_total, args=('c',['a','b','x']), axis=1)
df_test2.apply(find_match_total, args=('c',['a','b','x']), axis=1)
df_test3.apply(find_match_total, args=('c',['a','b','x']), axis=1)

I got weird results. I see df_test1 and df_test2 are modified inplace as desired (with 0) but df_test3 is still unchanged although df_test2 and df_test3 are the same data types and structure as tested above???
df_test1 is modified (0,x) ; (2,x)
    a   b   x   c   f
0   1   11  0   12  12
1   2   12  12  12  12
2   3   13  0   16  13
3   4   14  14  14  14
4   5   15  15  15  15
5   6   16  16  16  16

df_test2 is modified => column x is set to 0

     c           a          b            x  f
0   786.623802  589.967851  196.65595   0.0 0.0
1   786.623802  589.967851  196.65595   0.0 0.0
2   786.623802  589.967851  196.65595   0.0 0.0
3   786.623802  589.967851  196.65595   0.0 0.0
4   786.623802  589.967851  196.65595   0.0 0.0
5   786.623802  589.967851  196.65595   0.0 0.0
6   786.623802  589.967851  196.65595   0.0 0.0
7   786.623802  589.967851  196.65595   0.0 0.0

df_test3 read from excel is not modified
       c           a             b         x    f
0   786.623802  589.967851  196.65595   0.016   0
1   786.623802  589.967851  196.65595   0.016   0
2   786.623802  589.967851  196.65595   0.016   0
3   786.623802  589.967851  196.65595   0.016   0
4   786.623802  589.967851  196.65595   0.016   0
5   786.623802  589.967851  196.65595   0.016   0
6   786.623802  589.967851  196.65595   0.016   0
7   786.623802  589.967851  196.65595   0.016   0


Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question. pd.DataFrame(data2['data'], columns=data2['columns']) is not even possible, given data2 above. Also, please provide more details on what you expected to happen versus what actually happened. Currently, you are just asking for readers to debug some lines of code, without even explaining what the code is supposed to do.

None of your df was modified as df.apply returns a df and you need to assign it to a new variable. For example new_df = original_df.apply(my_func, axis=1) Also, your function should return something else None will be the result of your calcualtion.

@ouroboros1 sorry for that, I edited already.

@alec_djinn my function indeed modify dataframe. Please see the df_test1 and df_test2 after applying function.
